# Does a continuous zero-mean random variable necessarily have a probability density function symmetrical about the y axis?

Tags: probability-theory

I failed to come up with a counter-example, yet I'm not sure about the following proof for this statement to be true.

With X being a random variable with PDF $$f{_X}(x)$$, consider the expectation of $$Y = g{_X}(x) = X$$which is also a random variable, expressed as:

$$E[X] = ∫xf{_X}(x) dx$$

Since E[X] = 0, we can rewrite the integral as:

$$0 = ∫xf(x)dx$$

Now, let's consider the integral for the expected value of the negative of X:

$$E[-X] = ∫-xf(x)dx$$

This is essentially the same integral as before, but with the variable -x instead of x. Since the PDF represents the probability of X taking on a certain value, f(-x) is the probability density for the random variable -X.

Now, using the fact that the expected value of -X is also zero (E[-X] = 0), we can rewrite the integral as:

$$0 = ∫-xf(-x)dx$$

Comparing this expression with the previous integral, we see that the two integrals are equal. This implies that the probability density function f(-x) for the random variable -X is equal to the probability density function f(x) for the random variable X, but reflected about the y-axis.

Therefore, the PDF of X exhibits mirror symmetry around the y-axis, and this symmetry is a direct consequence of the zero-mean property of the random variable.

Comment: No this proof is not correct: just because the definite integrals agree does not mean that the integrands agree. As a counter example take any non-symmetric continuous distribution and substract the mean (e.g. exponential distribution).

Comment: Right, thanks. Just realized how silly my question was.